# JTAG Programmer for Xilinx CPLDs

Tags: xilinx, programmer

I have bought a Xilinx "Programmable Cable USB" so I can program the Xilinx CPLDs on my custom PCB. The PCBs are not ready yet. My question is, how do I test if this programmer is functional (I bought it on ebay). How do I test if Vivado is able to detect this device correctly?

[image]

Comment: I would guess plug in the USB side and see if Vivado says something about it? (I don't really know the answer)

Comment: I did plug it in. Viavdo says this: open_hw_target
INFO: [Labtoolstcl 44-466] Opening hw_target localhost:3121/xilinx_tcf/Xilinx/13620207920aea
ERROR: [Labtools 27-2269] No devices detected on target localhost:3121/xilinx_tcf/Xilinx/13620207920aea.
Check cable connectivity and that the target board is powered up then
use the disconnect_hw_server and connect_hw_server to re-register this hardware target.
ERROR: [Common 17-39] 'open_hw_target' failed due to earlier errors.
ERROR: [Labtoolstcl 44-513] HW Target shutdown. Closing target: localhost:3121/xilinx_tcf/Xilinx/13620207920aea

Comment: Is there a commnad-line tool with Vivado that I can use and it will list all the programmers detected by the program?

Comment: @quantum231 Which is exactly what I would expect to see given you don't have a powered up FPGA on the far end of that cable.

Comment: That error message sounds like it detected the dongle, and was able to communicate with it sufficiently to check whether there are any programmable chips attached to it. That's probably as good as you're going to get unless you want to buy a CPLD or FPGA demo board to test it with.

Comment: ok, this much will do. In your undestanding, what program is needed to compile design for the XC9572XL and XC2C32A CoolRunner-II CPLDs? Basically I am designing a small board with these to practice PCB design, since these have Quad Flat Package and only need 2 voltage rails, I chose to design board for them.

Comment: "what program is needed to compile design for the XC9572" Is the Xilinx Web Pack still a thing? https://www.xilinx.com/products/design-tools/ise-design-suite/ise-webpack.html  I believe that I used to use it with that exact chip...

Comment: Can this program work on windows 10 or I must get windows 7?

Comment: So, I got this programmer, I got a basic XC9572XL CPLD board, I downloaded the Xilinx ISE "14.7 Windows 10" and the Oracle VM Virtual Box. The ISE runs inside the VM Virtual Box to prevent incompatibility with the Windows 10 and this this program is required. I used the Project Navigator, the Xilinx Program Studio is not required. I was able to create ISE project targetting this device and was able to compile and download the bit stream successfully. The "LookAhead" option was not available so I wrote the pinout as a text file in the UCF file.

Answer (score 1):

(Since the question was basically answered in the comments...)

In my day, we just used the parallel/printer port.
[image: Bit-banging is not just for breakfast anymore!]

(Yes, I totally made this, stuffed it into a plastic box, and used it for years.)

Comment: I haven't seen a machine with an actual parallel port in many, many years. In the early oughties I used Macraigor parallel-port pods, and even then I struggled to provision machines that could use them. Not worth the hassle - better to move on.

Comment: Too bad that we do not have a parallel printer port anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Once you plug in the pod Vivado will see it, then attempt to identify devices on the scan chain. Since you don't have your board yet it won't show anything. Chances are good that the pod will work when you get your board back, they're pretty robust.

You have a backup plan if for some reason your pod doesn't work: get a Digilent JTAG adapter. They're based on the FTDI chip and work seamlessly with Vivado.

Comment: I did not know such a programmer existed as well. I have looked at the supported devices list. Since I am interested in XC9572XL and XC2C32A CoolRunner-II, is XC9572XL same as Xilinx 9500/9500XL CPLDs that is no longer supported?

Comment: That's something you'll need to check on with Xilinx. At any rate, the Digilent HS3 pod is compatible with ISE. More here: https://digilent.com/reference/_media/reference/programmers/jtag-hs3/jtag-hs3_rm.pdf Again, only if your Xilinx pod doesn't work...